# ASP Classic and Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, windows, asp-classic

We are moving our applications (ASP Classic/.NET 2.0/3.5/xx) to a new server and upgrade them to the latest (.NET 4.5.x). For some of the ASP Classic it was decided to move them as is as ASP Classic but must clean the code of the hard coded SQL Connection Strings and use Windows Authentication by using a Windows Login Account. In these ASP Classic we use ADODB/SQLOLEDB as dataconnections. Could I still use these drivers but login using Windows Authentication?

Comment: Good news, someone already asked this at [Classic ASP Integrated Security in connection string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500064/classic-asp-integrated-security-in-connection-string)

Comment: This one might also be helpful if that first one isn't:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547045/how-to-connect-to-ms-sql-server-database-from-asp-using-windows-authentication-s